# Finite topological groups

Tags: general-topology

This is a follow up to a previous question on topological groups. I asked whether there is a group equipped with a topology such that product is continuous but not inverse, and also vice versa. The two examples I received were both infinite sets. My question is, are there finite groups equipped with a topology where product is continuous but not inverse, and also vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In one direction: If $G$ is a finite group, then the inverse map can be expressed as $x \mapsto x^{|G|-1}$; therefore, if the product map is continuous, then so is the inverse map.

However, the other direction doesn't work: for example, consider the finite group $\mathbb{Z} / 7 \mathbb{Z}$, and put on it the topology of sets which are fixed under negation.  (So this topology has base $\{ \{ 0 \}, \{ 1, 6 \}, \{ 2, 5 \}, \{ 3, 4 \} \}$.)  Then it is clear that negation is continuous with respect to this topology.  On the other hand, $1 + 6 = 0$; but then in the product space, any neighborhood of $(1, 6)$ must contain $(1, 1)$.  Therefore, $\{ 0 \}$ is open, but the inverse image under the product map is not.